# Calculated column to fill missing IDs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to create a calculated column in a Big Query which does the following:

I have table with product ID and product segment ID. But the product segment values are partly missing. Therefore I would like to create another column "ProdSed ID Calc" where the missing product segment IDs "ProdSeg ID" are filled as shown below:

```html
Product ID     ProdSeg ID     ProdSed ID Calc
1              1              1
1              Null           1
1              Null           1
2              Null           5
2              5              5
2              5              5
3              Null           18
3              Null           18
3              18             18
```

Could anyone help me?

Kind regards
Albertok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BigQuery, you probably don't want to actually update the table.  Instead, you can generate them on the fly using:

```
select t.*,
       max(ProdSegID) over (partition by ProductId) as ProdSedID_Calc
from t;
```

You can put this logic into a view and query the view.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The solution from Gordon worked fine for me.

Comment: Kind regards
Albrecht

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the original table:

```
UPDATE Your_Table as A
SET ProdSegID = 
(Select [ProdSeg ID]     
FROM Your_Table as B
Where B.Product ID  = A.Product ID and [ProdSeg ID] is not null  )
```

If you need to do what you asked:

```
UPDATE Your_Table as A
SET [ProdSed ID Calc] = 
(Select [ProdSeg ID]     
FROM Your_Table as B
Where B.Product ID  = A.Product ID and [ProdSeg ID] is not null  )
```

But be careful here, make sure the `ProdSeg ID` (not null ones) for the one `Product ID` is **unique**.

Answer (score 0):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH segments AS (
  SELECT ProductID, MAX(ProdSegID) AS ProdSegIDCalc
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT t.ProductID, t.ProdSegID, s.ProdSegIDCalc
FROM yourTable AS t 
JOIN segments AS s 
ON t.ProductID = s.ProductID
ORDER BY ProductID
```

You can test/play with it using dummy data from your question:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ProductID, 1 AS ProdSegID UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 18  
),
segments AS (
  SELECT ProductID, MAX(ProdSegID) AS ProdSegIDCalc
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT t.ProductID, t.ProdSegID, s.ProdSegIDCalc
FROM yourTable AS t 
JOIN segments AS s 
ON t.ProductID = s.ProductID
ORDER BY ProductID
```

Note: me personally  - I would go with using [`Analytic Functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions) as it is suggested in Gordon's answer. But wanted to give you more options - as depends on your real use case it can be more or less useful